# RDF inferring subClass using OWL and Protégé

Tags: rdf, protege, inference-engine

I am looking to make an ontology that will allow classification of types to map to another application. I need to find all instances that are of type `Person` without the triples explicitly defining that `Jack` is a `Person`. Currently using Protege I have not been able to do so using only SubClasses.

Lets assume the following:

```
MaleCollegeStudent is a subclass of CollegeStudent. 
CollegeStudent is a subclass of Student.
Student is a subclass of Person.
```

`ApplicationPersonType` is an equivalent class of `Person`. This is used to explicitly map the application type from the RDF class.

```
Hierarchy:

MaleCollegeStudent 
    -> CollegeStudent 
        -> Student
            -> Person
            -> ApplicationPersonType
```

```
# Class Declarations
:MaleCollegeStudent a owl:Class .
:CollegeStudent a owl:Class .
:Student  a owl:Class .
:Person a owl:Class .
:ApplicationPersonType a owl:Class .

# SubClass Declarations
:MaleCollegeStudent rdfs:subClassOf :CollegeStudent .
:CollegeStudent rdfs:subClassOf :Student  .
:Student  rdfs:subClassOf :Person .

# Equivalence Declarations
:ApplicationPersonType owl:equivalentClass :Person .

# Instances
:Jack a :MaleCollegeStudent .
:Ellen a :Student  .

# Assumed Inferred Relations
:Jack a :Person .
:Jack a :Student .
:Jack a :CollegeStudent .
:Ellen a :Person .
:Jack a :ApplicationPersonType .
:Ellen a :ApplicationPersonType .
```

For some reason, The Protégé tool I am using does not give me the above inferred results. My assumption is that the inferencer does not work/ does not list inferences at that high of a hierarchy structure.

**Q1. Does the tool list EVERY inference? ie. will it short cut and only list direct inferences even though it is inferred that there are more links between higher levels of the hierarchy?**

To suit my requirements, I would like to have the relations inferred that:

Jack is of type `ApplicationPersonType`

Ellen is of type `ApplicationPersonType`

**Q2. Am I missing something in the above to achieve this?**

I can see inferencing working on the tool when I add domain and range to each class. Ideally, I would also like to know if there is a way to infer a type on a multi-level hierarchy with only subclass.

**Q3. Is it possible to infer that Jack is of type `ApplicationPersonType` without domain and range mapped for any items?**

Thanks in advance for the responses!

Comment: Q1: where do you look for the inference? For the classes, it doe not always show all instances. The reason for this is obvious, in a large ontology top level classes might have millions of individuals, that would make the UI sluggish. Please look directly at the individual to confirm that it works

Comment: Q3: I don't understand the question. `:Jack a :ApplicationPersonType .` follows directly by your class hierarchy

Comment: Q1. In Protege, I click the instance and it does not show me that it is of type ApplicationPersonType. 
Q3. It follows directly in the class hierarchy because i used owl:equivalent of. In protege it does not show me that Jack is an application person type. I even tried to query for instances of type applicatiopnpersontype. Nothing come up...